# Prestashop 1.7 invoice tax not showing

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

prestashop 1.7 invoice not showing tax rate details.please see the image for the reference. In this image left third row left box for tax details. But its not showing tax details. in the right side box showing tax rate. how can i show tax rate in left side box also.

[image]

Comment: You mean to display the tax percent?

Comment: Yes. tax is already applied.but not showing in invoice tax box

Comment: Any idea ??Please let me know..